# Check if the image is a JPEG

Tags: php, image

I need to check whether a given image is a JPEG.

```
if ($_FILES["fname"]["error"] > 0) {
    $imgData = "hyperlink/holder.jpg";
} else {
    $imgData ="hyperlink/" . $_FILES["fname"]["name"];
}
// Only accept jpg images
// pjpeg is for Internet Explorer should be jpeg
if (!($_FILES["fname"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg") ) {
    print "I only accept jpg files!";
    exit(0);
}
```

When it goes to first statement in the first if statement it always gives I only accept jpg files!

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 31):

Try the [exif_imagetype](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php) image function.

Example:

```
if(exif_imagetype($filepath) != IMAGETYPE_JPEG){
    echo 'Not a JPEG image';
}
```

Answer (score 6):

PHP has such good image-type support, i wonder why you are restricting your app. In just a couple lines of code you can deal with any input format and convert to jpeg, if that is a requirement...

```
$im = imagecreatefrompng(input_filename)
imagejpeg($im, output_filename);
```

Answer (score 6):

I believe the following works:

Also note that:

> (exif_imagetype($ImagePathAndName) == IMAGETYPE_JPEG)

only reads the first few bytes looking for an image header so isn't really good enough to confirm if an image is corrupt.

Below I have it in a logical “and” statement i.e. both of these tests must be passed in order for the image to qualify as being valid and non-corrupt etc:

```
if ((exif_imagetype($ImagePathAndName) == IMAGETYPE_JPEG) && (imagecreatefromjpeg( $ImagePathAndName ) !== false ))
{
echo 'The picture is a valid jpg<br>';
}
```

Note: You need to place this line of code at the top of the php code in order to avoid seeing the warning messages from imagecreatefromjpeg( $ImagePathAndName ) when it encounters a fake/corrupt image file.

```
ini_set(‘gd.jpeg_ignore_warning’, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `$_FILES`, you are relying on informations sent by the client, which is not the best thing to do (you've seen it's not always the same, and, if I remember correctly, `$_FILES['...']['type']` can be faked).

If you are using PHP >= 5.3 (or can install PECL packages), maybe you can give a look to the extension [Fileinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php). If you are using an older version, what about [`mime_content_type`](http://php.net/mime_content_type)?

And, as said by Scott, why allow only jpeg?

Looking about the code better : when you are in the first case (`error > 0`), you are assigning a default file to `$imgData`? Why the spaces around "hyperlink"?
And why do you always use to check the `content-type`, even if there was an error a couple of lines before?

To finish, did you have a look at the manual ([Handling file uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php))?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try creating an array of exceptions (the files you want the user to be able to upload).

```
// Hyperlink for your website
$hyperlink = "http://www.yourwebsitehere.com";

if($_FILES['fname']['error'] > 0)
{
    $image= $hyperlink . "/holder.jpg";
} 
else
{
    $image = $hyperlink . "/" . $_FILES['fname']['name'];
}

// Only accept files of jpeg format
$exceptions = array("image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/pjpeg");

foreach($exceptions as $value)
{
    if($_FILES['fname']['type'] != $value)
    {
        echo "I only accept jpeg images!";
        break; // Or exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: No assignment for `$_FILES['fname']['type']` will ever always skip the if block. (ie. a success)

Answer (score 0):

[Check the  **mime**](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)  (Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions) type of file with this code. And verify your desired type. You can also detect png,gif with this code.

```
 if($_FILES["fname"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
  {
      echo "File type is JPEG";
  }
```

Comment: a hacker can easily fake the mime type, though.

Comment: Downvote - this is not secure as @hanshenrik suggests. It might be useful as a first initial check to save some computing power in later steps such as using [fileinfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php).