# PHP: How would you check if the result string of file_get_contents() is a JPG image?

Tags: php

I am using `file_get_contents()` to pull some images from a remote server and I want to confirm if the result string is a JPG/PNG image before further processing, like saving it locally and create thumbs.

```
$string = file_get_contents($url);
```

How would you do this?

Comment: What about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141227/php-checking-if-the-images-is-jpg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [getimagesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)

```
$url = 'http://www.geenstijl.nl/archives/images/HassVivaCatFight.jpg';
$file = file_get_contents($url);
$tmpfname = tempnam("/tmp", "FOO");
$handle = fopen($tmpfname, "w");
fwrite($handle, $file);

$size = getimagesize($tmpfname);
if(($size['mime'] == 'image/png') || ($size['mime'] == 'image/jpeg')){
   //do something with the $file
   echo 'yes an jpeg of png';
}
else{
    echo 'Not an jpeg of png ' . $tmpfname .' '. $size['mime']; 
    fclose($handle);
}
```

I just tested it so it works. You need to make a temp file becouse the image functions work with local data and they only accept local directory path like 'C:\wamp2\www\temp\image.png'

If you do not use `fclose($handle);` PHP will automatically delete tmp after script ended.

Answer (score 6):

I got from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3312996/1401975) the starting bits for a JPG image. So basically what you could do is to check whether the starting bits are equal or not:

```
$url = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jh3mC.jpg?s=128&g=1';
$jpg = file_get_contents($url);

if(substr($jpg,0,3) === "\xFF\xD8\xFF"){
    echo "It's a jpg !";
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer to this question IMO since it doesn't require a temp file strategy or installed extensions.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

[exif_imagetype()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php)

to evaluate your file. Please do check the php manual.

**Edited :**

Please note that PHP_EXIF must be enabled. You can read more about it [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.exif.php)

Comment: PS: the PHP_EXIF extension must be installed & enabled

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV thanks for the correction, i edited it as you said.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe standart PHP function exif_imagetype() http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php