# How to restrict a .exe.png or renaming .exe file to png file to upload in angular 8

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, file-upload, angular8

i was accepting only image upload file type JPG,JPEG,PNG,TIFF, but i can upload .exe file format,just by renaming it e.g: dell.exe.png or dell.exe to dell.png

Comment: After i researched about it and i finally found some solution, we can check the dimension of the image file, if it is not display dimension of img than it is not an image file.But still we need to check from server side also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to truly restrict what kinds of data get uploaded are to analyse the data *on the server* after it has been uploaded.

Any client-side check can be bypassed. You could add more complexity to the client-side check (adding in checks on the bytes in the file via FileReader) but if someone is going to the effort to slip past your existing client-side checks, that is unlikely to stop them.

For an example in PHP, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141227/check-if-the-image-is-a-jpeg).

Comment: True, as once you change an extension of file browser can't identify it's last extension, so better to put check on the server side.