# web page image is showing black on mobile browser

Tags: html, image, mobile

I have web page (php page) and it is showing the image very well for any browser in my desktop, ipad (9.7 inch or bigger) but never show in iphone, android phone, and ipad mini. The mobile browser only shows black image.

1. I wonder that the image is too large (jpg), but same jpg file is showing well in desktop browser but is showing black in mobile browser.
2. I research google. Someone says this image may use CMYK format. How can I know this image is CMYK format? is it the issue?

Does anyone know how to fix the issue?

Give you an image sample

link:  http://www.cbeiji.com/upload1812/20200308120858161866827.jpg

html:

```
<img alt="" src="http://www.cbeiji.com/upload1812/20200308120858161866827.jpg">
```

Desktop browser shows well.

Mobile browser doesn't show up. It is a black rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a JPEG, it's a PNG.

[image: Hex Editor]

Now, the browser doesn't really know or care what the filename is, but your server is using the `.jpg` extension to determine what `Content-Type` header to send back.  Your server is sending:

```
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

Obviously, since it's not a JPEG, some clients are going to have a problem with this.  For the ones that are working... the browser is being nice to you.

By the way, you can verify this stuff yourself using one of the many metadata viewers online.  For example:  https://exifmeta.com/

Comment: Thanks Brad for your anwser! I just come back to see the comment. So do  you mean the jpg is actually a png file? Do you know how to correct the extension by using php? This is a sample image only. If I don't want to do Right click to change it to png one by one if multiple images, how can we use php to recognize the type and then program to change it to the actual image type?

Comment: @huichen There are a lot of Stack Overflow answers on the topic.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/28077738/362536  https://stackoverflow.com/a/1141249/362536

Answer (score 0):

1. Use an image editor and save the file as a regular jpg (or just right-click save as)
2. Make sure there is no transparency added

first check it with one image, see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks omadawn for your anwser! I just come back to see the comment. How do I know the image is transparency added or not? For a bunch of images, how do we change them to the correct type of image, like 100 image with .jpg, how to change them at once or using programming language?